# Permission denied trying to setup postgres sql

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, postgresql

I'm trying to setup Dspace for a uni job here, but this Protgres SQL is asking for a password (For the postgres user) but it's supposed to be indent, I have no idea what's going on.

So, When I try to

```
sudo -u postgres sql
```

It gives :

```
could not change directory to "/home/myuser": Permission denied psql (9.3.6)
```